# C# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden | Only Few Times

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am posting a request over one api url in a bulk.

Lets say I have posted it 30 times in parallel. Every time the api key in the header is same. All the parameters are same.

What I observed is , it fails for first 5 times with - 401 Unauthorized and then for rest of the 25 times it gives results.

To get the response , I am using below code -

```
lHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Api-Key:" + lApiKey);
        lHttpWebRequest.Host = mConfig.GetHostName(mContext);
        lHttpWebRequest.Expect = "100";
        lHttpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;

        Stream lWriter = lHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        lWriter.Write(lData, 0, lData.Length);
        lWriter.Close();

        ///====================================================================
        /// Here the response is processed 
        ///====================================================================
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse lHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)lHttpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                ///====================================================================
                ///Process the Response
                ///====================================================================
                lResponse = SupplierConnectorHelper.GetUncompressedResponse((HttpWebResponse)lHttpWebResponse);
            }
        }
```

What could be the reason it fails few times with - `The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden`

Confusing point is , if it would be credentials / ApiKey issue , it would have failed for all requests. But its failing with above error for only few requests.

Comment: Could it be rate-limiting on the API? Not all APIs use the expected response (429).

Comment: 401 or 403 or both of them? 401 typically means the token is invalid. 403 typically means, the authentication has worked, but the user is not allowed to execute the request. But there is no guarantee, the author of the api follows these guidelines. The only one who can give a definitive answer, is the provider of the API.

Comment: Be sure to call `Dispose()` on your disposable objects, including `lWriter` and any others.  I've seen cases where missing resource deallocations can affect the integrity of subsequent calls.